# Strange behaviour on array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

this is another why is this happening question.  I output an array in my view and it clearly shows 3 array elements.  I need to output this number so I do

```
<td>{{ count($project->projectTemplate) or '' }}</td>
```

The output of the above is 1 when it should be 3.  However, if I remove the or section e.g.

```
<td>{{ count($project->projectTemplate) }}</td>
```

The output is 3.  Why does the or mess up the count of my array?

Thanks

Comment: Whats the point in the `or ''`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't mess up anything it works as expected.
This is boolean statement `count($project->projectTemplate) or ''` and it results to `true` if `$project->projectTemplate` has more than 1 element.
`{{ true }}` results to 1 because it's almost equivalent of `echo true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<td>{{isset($project->projectTemplate) ? count($project->projectTemplate) : null }}</td>
```